# In d3 js how to append the additional text as tool tip on the circles

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, bubble-chart

I am working on a d3 sample http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/:

[image]

I am trying to add title for circles with  with the name as well as checkin details.

following is the modified code for the display year function (rest of the code almost no change,,,):

```
 // Updates the display to show the specified year.
  function displayYear(year) {
    dot.data(interpolateData(year), key)
    .call(position)
    .sort(order);

    dot.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.name});

    dot.text(function(d) { return d.name + "~"+ d.checkins + d.Checkintimes; });

    label.text(Math.round(year));

      }
// Interpolates the dataset for the given (fractional) year.
  function interpolateData(year) {
    return nations.map(function(d) {
      return {
        name: d.name,
        region: d.region,
        checkins: interpolateValues(d.checkins, year),
        teamsize: interpolateValues(d.teamsize, year),
        Checkintimes: interpolateValues(d.Checkintimes, year)
      };

    });
  }
```

However the same is not appearing as title in the circles. I just want to append the checkin detail with the circle.

My json file contains the following:

[
{

```
"name":"Search&Navigator",
"region":"IPScience",
"checkins":[[2000,100],[2001,200],[2002,300],[2003,275],[2004,222],[2005,280],[2006,281],[2007,400],[2008,55],[2009,300]],
"teamsize":[[2000,10],[2001,7],[2002,7],[2003,12],[2004,5],[2005,3],[2006,10],[2007,12],[2008,12],[2009,10]],
"Checkintimes":[[2000,40],[2001,50],[2002,60],[2003,50],[2004,40],[2005,30],[2006,30],[2007,35],[2008,30],[2009,30]]
```

}
]

Comment: Where is `label` defined? Do you have a working version you could post on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `dot` doesn't contain a reference to the `title` element. Simply change the function that appends it to do what you want:

```
dot.append("title")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name + "~"+ d.checkins + d.Checkintimes; });
```

Comment: It is working fine. Is it possible to show the actual values of the json data than the runtime data. Since it is using interapolation, the value is differing slightly. It would be great if we can fetch the data of the jsondata when the year changes. Can it be included in the existing function itself or i have to write a seperate function for this

Comment: The value will only be different if the value for that particular year is missing.